# String to string array conversion in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a string:

> [('I', 'PRP'), ('have', 'VBP'), ('lost', 'VBN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('pant', 'NN')]

Now I need to take the words in between single quotes in an **array**. as example:

> ```
>  array1[0] = I 
>  array1[1] = PRP 
>  array1[2] = have 
>  array1[3] = VBP
>  And so on ...
> ```

The number of entries *[assuming ('x', 'y') makes an entry]* is variable in the original string. And the array needs to be a **string** array, not something like numpy ndarray. Now, how to do that with **Python**?

*I also have a List object just like the original string. If the same result can be achieved by processing the list object, that would also work fine.*

Comment: You have a list of tuples you need a nested loop to access the inner values

Comment: The thing in your 1st codeblock is a list of tuples of strings. The arrays provided by the Python [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module are primarily designed to handle numerical data; they can be used to create arrays of chars, but not arrays of strings. I don't understand why you can't just construct a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

result = list(chain.from_iterable(your_list))
```

[`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) does exactly what you'd think it does: it flattens the given iterable (converts nested structure into a chain).

Comment: This one helped me

Answer (score 2):

It's same like make list of list into a single list,

```
In [3]: lst = [('I', 'PRP'), ('have', 'VBP'), ('lost', 'VBN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('pant', 'NN')]
In [4]: print [i for j in lst for i in j]
Out[4]: ['I', 'PRP', 'have', 'VBP', 'lost', 'VBN', 'a', 'DT', 'pant', 'NN']
```